# Tracking IP address with a switch sandwiched between a client and server

Tags: c#, .net, ip

There are two application servers(IIS). There is a switch or a virtual IP which load balances requests for the 2 servers.

I need to track requestor(client) IP address from my .NET application.

The code `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` is giving the switch IP address.

The request first hits switch then request is diverted to either of the server, in this process my application is getting switch IP address for that code and client IP is masked.

Comment: Check the [x-forwarded-for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] is giving null or no value. Please help

Comment: what version of IIS is running on the load-balancer and how are you doing the load-balancing?

Comment: Load balancer is a router device which routes requests to application servers. There is no IIS on this device. Application server has IIS 7.0

Comment: OL well its a config problem on your router, not an IIS problem so I probably can't help you.  Your router needs to be configured to populate the x-forwarded-for header, You might want to go to serverfault.com and ask how to make the router populate the x-forwarded-for header - remember to give the make and model of the router.  Whomever set up the router as a load-balancer should have done this as part of the work.